# Can I inherit WebsiteCrmPartnerAssign class of Reseller module in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-9

How to inherit WebsiteCrmPartnerAssign class of Reseller module in odoo. Since the class name is not mentioned....please help me with this qwery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit the class like, how you inherit a Python class. I didn't try it, but i have read it from a book and it should work.

```
from openerp.addons.website_crm_partner_assign.controllers.main import WebsiteCrmPartnerAssign

class MyClass(WebsiteCrmPartnerAssign):
   ...
```